# How to identify all rules that match pattern type?

Tags: pattern-matching, symbols, rule

I would like to be extend the below solution to be able to find get all rules from the list `step[2]` that match the generic pattern k*_Digit_*p. Where k and p are not generic characters but form part of the symbol name. Unfortunately I've stalled in my understanding of symbolic pattern matches, without converting the symbol names to strings. How can I define the generic pattern above without converting to strings and performing `StringMatchQ[]` test?

```
params={k1p,k1m,k2p,k2m,nfb,pfb};
step[1]={1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.};
parameterLimits={k1p->{0.25,1.5}};
step[2]=step[1][[#]]+RandomReal[{-1.,1.}]&/@Range[Length@params];
step[2]=Thread[params->step[2]]
```

> ```
> k1p->0.0432604,k1m->0.898291,k2p->0.436556,k2m->0.917969,nfb->0.519343,pfb->1.00006}
> ```

```
Cases[step[2], PatternSequence[k1p -> _]]
```

> ```
> {k1p->0.0432604}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can avoid using strings, but that doesn't mean the output will contain strings.

```
Pick[step[2], StringMatchQ[ToString /@ step[2][[All, 1]], "k*p"]]
```

> ```
> {k1p -> 1.09503, k2p -> 1.32185}
> ```

Comment: I see, converting to strings is still extremely fast so that will not be a problem. And having the output as an expression will make testing each element of the returning list of rules straight forward.

Answer (score 3):

I would use `Cases` with a condition and `SymbolName`.

```
Cases[step[2], (symbol_ -> _) /; StringMatchQ[SymbolName[symbol], "k*p"]]
```

Another solution:

```
step[2] /. (symbol_ -> value_) /; Not@StringMatchQ[SymbolName[symbol], "k*p"] :> Nothing
```

This solution makes use of [`Nothing`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Nothing.html) which is new in Mathematica version 10.2. `Nothing` could be replaced by `Sequence[]` is earlier versions.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a pattern, you could use

```
Cases[step[2],
  Alternatives@@HoldPattern/@Thread[ToExpression[Names["Global`k*p"]]->_Real]]

(* {k1p -> 1.5396, k2p -> 1.91751} *)
```

Technically this does not convert anything to strings, it just looks up all the user-defined names that match `"k*p"`. It's not really elegant though.

Alternatively you can use `Select` as well:

```
Select[step[2], StringMatchQ[ToString[#[[1]]], "k*p"] &]

(* {k1p -> 1.5396, k2p -> 1.91751} *)
```